# maximum recursion depth exceeded writing a simple function

Tags: python, function, refactoring

```py
def AtomicWeight(Z: "int"):    
    return AtomicWeight(Z)
    
z = 1.45
AtomicWeight(z)
type(z)
```

Could someone explain what this function is doing and why it's saying maximum recursion depth exceeded? I tried increasing maximum recursion but it won't work. Is there another way to write this?

Comment: You call the function itself inside its body. It's called a recursion. You call it once, which calls the function again, which calls the function again and so on... Nothing is there to stop the infinite calls. As this function currently stands, it doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: How would you rewrite this function? Also, could you tell me what (Z: "int") does?

Comment: It's called a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). It says that `Z` should be an integer. Also I belive it's `Z: int` and not `Z: "int"`. Anyways, it's not really clear what do you want to achieve with this function, as it does nothing other than throw a RecursionError.

Answer (score 0):

The function is calling itself over and over again because there is no `return` in the function. After calling the function x times the maximum recursion depth is exceeded, and Python stops running the code.

This could be prevented by changing your example to:

```
def AtomicWeight(Z: "int"):
    return Z * 2  # times 2 is just example to let the function do something
z = 1.45
z = AtomicWeight(z)
```

Now the `AtomicWeight` function doesn't call itself anymore and returns a value.